# Model binding with dynamic type in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is it somehow possible to bind the model in a form to a dynamic/object parameter?

```
public class ExampleClass:
{
    public dynamic exampleAttribute { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, dynamic> exampleDict {get; set;}

}
```

```
@model ExampleClass
<input asp-for="exampleAttribute"  /> 
@foreach (var key in exampleDict.Keys){
  <input asp-for="exampeDict[key]"  /> 
}
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, but having only null as a result in any spot.

Comment: Form fields are submitted as string. ASP.NET Core uses model binding to bind fields to a class. You can accept a string then parse it manually.

Comment: So basically building and casting from the passed IFormCollection fields instead?

Comment: Yep, that's right.